# Accessing a two dimensional JSON array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I have a nested data structure / JSON, how can I access a specific value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-i-access-a-specific-value)

I am using the US Census API and end up with a two dimensional json array from a jQuery.get() request. My result (data) looks like this:

`[["P0010001","NAME","state","county","tract"], ["2703","Census Tract 4001.01","17","119","400101"], ["5603","Census Tract 4001.02","17","119","400102"], ["4327","Census Tract 4002","17","119","400200"]]`

It looks exactly like a two dimensional javascript array, but I cannot access it like one when I try:

```
var population = data;
alert(population[1][0]);
```

Is there a way to convert the json array into a javascript array, or to convert it to a string, which could then be put into an array?

Comment: if you can use the $.getJSON() instead of a get. The getJson automatically converts the data recieved into a js object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse`:

```
var population = JSON.parse(data);
alert(population[1][0]);
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6CGh8/